# Set multiple fields of form on particular radio button click

Tags: php, javascript, radio-button

I'm developing a web app in which I've to integrate a Paypal account. There are many radio buttons on the page that represents various credits and it's price and like wise. My Problem is, I want some functionality through which I can set various other fields of form on one of the radio button click. And those values are different for every radio button.

```
<form action='<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>' method='post' name='form'>
    <div class="crea_paka_title">Creadit Pakages</div>
    <?php
    foreach($admin_credits as $credits){ 
    ?>
        <div class="creadit_fields">
            <span class="for_radio">
                <input type="radio" name="1" id="<?php echo $credits['AdminCredit']['id'];?>" value="" />
            </span>
            <span class="for_creadit">
                <?php echo $credits['AdminCredit']['tx_total_credits']; ?> Credits
            </span>
            <span class="for_cre_value">
                $<?php echo $credits['AdminCredit']['nu_total_price']; ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='<?php echo $credits['AdminCredit']['tx_total_credits'];?> Credits'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='<?php echo $credits['AdminCredit']['id'];?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='<?php echo $credits['AdminCredit']['nu_total_price'];?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
```

Like as above in my code I've to change the values of inputs on radio button click. Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: @DainisAbols : no. I'm not talking about it. I've to set multiple input fields on single radio button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery will do it:

```
$("#rbID").click(finction(){
  $("otherRB").attr("checked",true);
});
```